# How can I crop an Image with 1:1 aspect ratio using pillow in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop the image into 1:1 aspect ratio with the following code.

```
from PIL import Image

def crop_image(image):
    width, height = image.size
    print(width, height)
    aspect_ratio = width/float(height)

    if aspect_ratio < 1:
        bottom_offset = height/2 - width/2
        top = height - bottom_offset
        bottom = top + width
        left = 0
        right = left+width
        print((top, bottom, left, right))
        new_image = image.crop((left,top, right, bottom))
        print(new_image.size)
        new_image.save("new.jpg")

image = Image.open('test.jpg')
crop_image(image)
```

but it is not giving me the right output. 
I am using the following image:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDB5.jpg)

and it gives me the following output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuCnv.jpg)

it gives me the right dimensions but not the right output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare width and height to find which side should be sliced.
The crop offset of two side border equals to the difference divided by 2.

## Numpy

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
def crop_image(img):
    width, height = image.size
    if width == height:
        return img
    img = np.array(img)
    offset  = int(abs(height-width)/2)
    if width>height:
        img = img[:,offset:(width-offset),:]
    else:
        img = img[offset:(height-offset),:,:]
    return Image.fromarray(img)

image = Image.open(r"test.jpg")
crop_image(image)
```

## PIL

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(r"test.jpg")
def crop_image(image):
    width, height = image.size
    if width == height:
        return image
    offset  = int(abs(height-width)/2)
    if width>height:
        image = image.crop([offset,0,width-offset,height])
    else:
        image = image.crop([0,offset,width,height-offset])
    return image
image = Image.open(r"test.jpg")
crop_image(image)
```